# Is there a way to hide files after compressed?

Tags: security, encryption, compression, zip, 7zip

I've been trying to encrypt some data with 7za (don't even know if it's secure enough) but, even after encryption and compressing, it would be possible to check which files my compressed file contains. Is there a way to hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encrypt the archive header as well with the `-mhe=on` argument to `7za`. Note that this only works for producing `.7z` files. From `man 7za`:

> #### SWITCHES
>
> ⋮
>         **`-mhe=on|off`**
>                7z format only : enables or disables archive header encryption (Default : off)